# get keyboard cursor position - PowerShell

Tags: powershell

How can I get the position of the keyboard cursor using powershell??

My goal is to click on one of these squares dynamically. I can't use enter or space with powershell's `sendkeys` or else I would have been done already. lol

For example - this is powershell code that can find the exact position of your mouse:

```
Start-Sleep 5
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
 
$X = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position.X
$Y = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position.Y
 
Write-Output "X: $X | Y: $Y"
```

I also know how to left click with the mouse as well:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -MemberDefinition '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern void mouse_event(int flags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int info);' -Name U32 -Namespace W;

[Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = "1254,564" #This is a position on your screen at the bottom right.
[W.U32]::mouse_event(6,0,0,0,0); #this is the actual mouse click event.
```

So I:

1. Know how to get a position of the mouse
2. Know how to click on the screen using the mouse

But I would like to figure out how to:
Get the position of a highlighted or tabbed area (Most likely the keyboard cursor position on the screen). - The idea being is that if I can use powershell to tab to where I want, then I just need the mouse to get to the same position so I can double click instead of using enter or space on the keyboard (which I wish worked but this application is odd)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out but it requires **autohotkey's ImageSearch** to get the job done.

Here test code I used. I start off with powershell waiting 5 seconds so I can move over to the screen that I am testing. Then I have it simulate typing in the test window so I can see the cursor highlight one of the views (in this case a view called "Internet Access"). Afterwards, I use Autohotkey to try and find the highlighted cursor based on the snapshot image I took. Once it finds it, it double clicks on that position on the screen.

This requires that you take a snapshot of the screen and crop exact where you are trying to have the mouse move to.

This requires you knowing the resolution size of your screen.

Here is the code:

test.ps1

```
Start-Sleep 6
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.SendKeys("Internet Access")
Start-Sleep 1
.\MyScript.ahk
```

MyScript.ahk

```
ImageSearch, X, Y, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, croppedimage.png
MouseMove,%x%,%y%
Click
Click
```

Links that helped me:
Imagesearch documentation from autohotkey: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm

Youtube video on how to use Imagesarch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oAkivSDrktE